# How to make Bootstrap navbar brand image larger

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I am having a slight issue trying to increase the size of my navbar brand image i have inside my main navigation. It seem like it wont go any larger the 50px. I would like it around 100px high but just cant seem to work out how to do it. I currently have it in the center of the navigation with the burger menu along side it.

Would anyone know how to achieve what i am trying to do?

HTML:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default custom-nav">
  <div class="container">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"></a>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">About <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">History</a></li>
            <li><a href="team.php">Meet The Team</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Facilities</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Opening Times</a></li>
            <li><a href="membership.php">Membership</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Diary</a></li>
        <li><a href="lessons.php">Lessons</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"> Events<span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="corporate.php">Corporate Days </a></li>
            <li><a href="hens_stags.php">Hens & Stags</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Group Bookings</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Gallary</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="contact.php">Contact</a>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div>
  <!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```

CSS:

```
 .navbar-brand {
    background: url(../img/logo.png);
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
    width: 300px;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    left: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    padding: 0;
  }

.navbar-default .navbar-toggle .icon-bar {
  background-color: #fff;
}

.navbar .navbar-nav {
  display: inline-block;
  float: none;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.navbar .navbar-collapse {
  text-align: center;
}

.custom-nav {
  color: #fff;
  background: #718373;
  border-radius: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  border: 0;
}

.custom-nav .navbar-nav>li>a {
  color: #fff;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.custom-nav .navbar-nav>li>a:hover,
.custom-nav .navbar-nav>li>a:focus {
  color: #fff;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:focus,
.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:hover {
  background: none;
}

.custom-nav .navbar-nav>.open>a,
.custom-nav .navbar-nav>.open>a:focus,
.custom-nav .navbar-nav>.open>a:hover {
  color: #fff;
  background: none;
}

.custom-nav .navbar-nav li {
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  width: 150px;
}

.dropdown-menu {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background: #718373;
  border: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  min-width: 90px;
}

.dropdown-menu li:last-child a {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.dropdown-menu>li>a {
  display: block;
  clear: both;
  font-weight: normal;
  color: #fff;
  width: 95%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px 0;
}

.dropdown-menu>li>a:focus,
.dropdown-menu>li>a:hover {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  background: none;
  outline: 2px solid white;
  outline-offset: -2px;
}
```

This is how it looks at the moment

[image: Logo image]

EDIT after adding

```
.navbar-header .navbar-brand {
  height: 100px;
}
```

[image: new logo image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your styles are overwritten by Bootstraps navbar styles. Use [higher specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) to make your styles apply to the navbar-brand, e.g. with

```css
.navbar-header .navbar-brand {
  height: 100px;
}
```

This way you can overwrite the height.

```css
.navbar-header .navbar-brand {
  background: url(../img/logo.png);
  background: url(//placehold.it/300x100);
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
  height: 100px;
  width: 300px;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  left: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  padding: 0;
  : #fff;
}
.navbar .navbar-nav {
  display: inline-block;
  float: none;
  vertical-align: top;
}
.navbar .navbar-collapse {
  text-align: center;
}
.custom-nav {
  color: #fff;
  background: #718373;
  border-radius: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  border: 0;
}
.custom-nav .navbar-nav>li>a {
  color: #fff;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.custom-nav .navbar-nav>li>a:hover,
.custom-nav .navbar-nav>li>a:focus {
  color: #fff;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:focus,
.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:hover {
  background: none;
}
.custom-nav .navbar-nav>.open>a,
.custom-nav .navbar-nav>.open>a:focus,
.custom-nav .navbar-nav>.open>a:hover {
  color: #fff;
  background: none;
}
.custom-nav .navbar-nav li {
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  width: 150px;
}
.dropdown-menu {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background: #718373;
  border: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  min-width: 90px;
}
.dropdown-menu li:last-child a {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.dropdown-menu>li>a {
  display: block;
  clear: both;
  font-weight: normal;
  color: #fff;
  width: 95%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px 0;
}
.dropdown-menu>li>a:focus,
.dropdown-menu>li>a:hover {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  background: none;
  outline: 2px solid white;
  outline-offset: -2px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<nav class="navbar navbar-default custom-nav">
  <div class="container">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"></a>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">About <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">History</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="team.php">Meet The Team</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Facilities</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Opening Times</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="membership.php">Membership</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Diary</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="lessons.php">Lessons</a>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"> Events<span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="corporate.php">Corporate Days </a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="hens_stags.php">Hens & Stags</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Group Bookings</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Gallary</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="contact.php">Contact</a>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div>
  <!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```

Comment: Thanks for this mate, i have tested and it seems that the logo is now hiding behind the image as its larger. Ideally i would like it to push the content below it down.

Comment: Ok, if you want it to be inside the elements flow you cannot use `position: absolute;`...

Comment: You also need to make the navbar higher, or set the height to auto so it accommodates.

Comment: andreas - Thanks for that it was the absolute positioning that was causing it like you mention! got rid of that and it looks right now. Sometimes the obvious things are so easy to miss!! Thanks again to you and everyone who helped